# having a hard time calling a custom fucntion on every button click in flutter

Tags: flutter

i was thinking if it is possible to call my custom function on every button on Click , without having to call that manually ?
for example , i wanna tell the app to wait for a second when any button is clicked.
is there any way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom button and use it instead of whatever buttons being used.

Here's a short example for your case:

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() onPressed;
  final String text;
  const CustomButton({super.key, required this.onPressed, required this.text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FilledButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), onPressed);
        },
        child: Text(text));
  }
}
```

Comment: damn, how come i didnt think that way. thanks alotttt.